# Jacobian matrix of complex mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, jacobian

I am reading the visual complex analysis book and currently the chapter about an concept called "amplitwist". I read that the complex mapping like 
$$
z \mapsto z^2 
$$
$$
z = re^{i\theta} 
$$

can be expressed locally as an amplitwist (amplification + rotation) which can also be encoded in Jacobian matrix like

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}$$

so I calculate $z^2$ as 
$$
z^2 = r^2 e^{2i\theta} = r^2(\cos(2\theta) + i\sin(2\theta))
$$
$$
u = r^2 \cos(2\theta)
$$
$$
v = r^2 \sin(2\theta)
$$
therefore
$\partial_x u = 2r \cos(2\theta) + r^2 (\cos(2\theta)\frac{d}{dx}) = 2r \cos(2\theta)$

so it means the first element of jacobian matrix should have an argument of $2\theta$ but in the book it is just $\theta$

What I do wrong so I got this argument doubled?

Comment: $u=x^2-y^2, u_x=2x=2r\cos \theta$; you forgot $r_x, \theta_x$ in the chain rule

Comment: Can you show me the proper equation for $\partial_x u$ ?

Comment: in polar coordinates (as otherwise, it is trivial as noted), you have to use that $r_x=\cos \theta, \theta_x=-\sin \theta /r$, so the equation becomes (chain rule) $\partial_x u = 2rr_x \cos(2\theta) - 2r^2 \theta_x \sin(2\theta)=2r(\cos \theta \cos 2\theta+\sin \theta \sin 2\theta)=2r\cos \theta$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but how did you get $r_x = cos(0)$ to me $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ So $x = r cos(\theta)$ similary what is $\theta_x$ ?

Comment: Just differentiate the above and you get $r_x= x/r= \cos \theta$

Comment: I am a bit confused by your notation:  what is $r_x$ to you? Is it a derivative of r in respect to x or is it a projection of r onto x axis?

Comment: I believe your $r_x $ is indeed the derivative of $r$ -> $\frac{dr}{dx}$. I managed to get the expression for $\frac{dr}{dx} = r' = cos(\theta)$ as in your case but how did you calculated $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$ ? Maybe first what was your starting equation for $\theta$ ?

Comment: $r_x = dr/dx$ as is the usual notation - for theta, same $\theta=\arctan y/x$ and you differentiate (a more elegant way is to invert the matrix of the partials of $x,y$ wr $r, \theta$ but the above is direct and fairly easy anyway

Comment: Ok tangens function is clever as it doesn't involve $r$ which depends on $x$ so the calculations should be easier. However when I do $tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ I get $ - \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ this is also the result from wolfram https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28y%2Fx%29%27. So what magic have you done so it became $-\frac{sin(\theta)}{r}$? :)

Comment: okay I see it now $\theta' = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and it is indeed $-\frac{sin}{r}$ Thanks @Conrad! :)

Comment: Excellent and happy to be of help